# Query builder join on ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use query builder to select all the categories that belong to a certain `superCategory` (`category` and `superCategory` have a many to many relationship).

However, I am unable to build a correct query builder sentence because I don't know how to reference to the `superCategory` from my `category`as there is no `superCategory` field inside my category ID.

The objects in the database look like :

```
Category:
  id
  name

SuperCategory
  id
  name

categories_superCategories
  id
  category_id
  superCategory_id
```

Here are the definition of my objects (yml files):

```
YOP\YourOwnPoetBundle\Entity\TraitCategory:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: YOP\YourOwnPoetBundle\Repository\TraitCategoryRepository
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    name:
      type: string
      length: '255'
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
  manyToMany:
    superCategories:
      targetEntity: SuperCategory
      joinTable:
        name: traitCategories_superCategories
        joinColumns:
          traitCategory_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          superCategory_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

and

```
YOP\YourOwnPoetBundle\Entity\SuperCategory:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: YOP\YourOwnPoetBundle\Repository\SuperCategoryRepository
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    name:
      type: string
      length: '255'
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
  manyToMany:
    msgCategories:
      targetEntity: MsgCategory
      mappedBy: superCategories
    traitCategories:
      targetEntity: TraitCategory
      mappedBy: superCategories
```

How would I build a query builder sentence to get the categories that belong to a certain `superCategory`?

The query inside my `CategoryRepository`:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->innerJoin( ?????? )
            ->setParameter('superCategoryName', $superCategoryName);
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Got it :

```
public function findBySuperCategoryName($superCategoryName)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->innerJoin('c.superCategories', 's', 'WITH', 's.name = :superCategoryName')
            ->setParameter('superCategoryName', $superCategoryName);
}
```

The problem was that I had to ask for c.superCategories and not c.superCategory !

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2020! Thank you.

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2021! Thank you.

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2022! Thank you

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2023! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('s')
        ->from('SuperCategory', 's')
        ->innerJoin('s.Category c ON c.category_id = s.superCategory_id')
        ->where('s.name = :superCategoryName')
        ->setParameter('superCategoryName', $superCategoryName)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```